# Can't submit form of table data using Laravel

Tags: php, html, laravel, form-submit

The form doesn't get submitted when clicking on the button and frankly I have no idea why it doesn't.

I have other pages with the same type of forms in my website but those work fine.

Here is the Html `form` that I want to submit.

```
<form action="/store-absence" method="POST">
    {{ csrf_field() }}
    <thead>
    <tr role="row">
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Date</th>
        <th>Attended</th>
    </thead>
    <tbody>

    <?php date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Baghdad') ?>
    @foreach ($students as $student)
    <tr>
        <input type="hidden" name="student_id[]" id="" value="{{$student->id}}">
        <input type="hidden" name="date" value="{{date('Y-m-d')}}">
        <td colspan=""> {{$student->name}} </td>
        <td colspan=""> {{date('Y-m-d')}} </td>
        <td colspan="1">
            <input style="border:none" type="checkbox" name="attended[]" id="">
        </td>
    </tr>
    @endforeach

    </tbody>

    </table>

    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-block btn-primary btn-lg">
        Insert
    </button>
</form>
```

Comment: Maybe the missing `<table>` tag is confusing your browser. Does it work when you add it?

Comment: No, the tag actually exists but it is before the form.  @HappyAnt

Comment: Try to clear cache or restart web server/browser. Your code should work.

Comment: Tried that but still didn't work, I have tested it on different browsers but the problem is likely in the code. @Phil

Answer (score 2):

When you add a table you have to start it with the open and close `<table>` tag.

here your updated code.

```
<form action="/store-absence" method="POST">
    <table>
        {{ csrf_field() }}
        <thead>
        <tr role="row">
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Date</th>
            <th>Attended</th>
        </thead>
        <tbody>

        <?php date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Baghdad') ?>
        @foreach ($students as $student)
        <tr>
            <input type="hidden" name="student_id[]" id="" value="{{$student->id}}">
            <input type="hidden" name="date" value="{{date('Y-m-d')}}">
            <td colspan=""> {{$student->name}} </td>
            <td colspan=""> {{date('Y-m-d')}} </td>
            <td colspan="1">
                <input style="border:none" type="checkbox" name="attended[]" id="">
            </td>
        </tr>
        @endforeach

        </tbody>

    </table>

    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-block btn-primary btn-lg">
        Insert
    </button>
</form>
```

if there any question comment below.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was with the `<table>` tag indeed, it was opened before the form and closed inside the 
 and that confused the browser I suppose! 
 
I wasted **5 hours** of my time for that simple mistake.